# Convert rotation angle in world space to local space cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Is there a simple way (ie an api) that converts an angle of rotation in world space to local space of a CCNode?  I know the angle of rotation a node needs to have on the screen, but the node is nested deeply in node hierarchy and I would like to set its angle so that it matches what I want.  If there's no api, what CC api calls should I make?  Something like this:

```
CCNode * myLocalNode;
float myLocalAngle = CCAngleConvertFromWorldToNode(myLocalNode,myWorldAngle);
myLocalNode -> setRotation(myLocalAngle);
```

Comment: add the node's rotation plus the rotation of all its parents, then add your angle (in degrees). If needed adjust the result to be in 0-359 range

Comment: That's the idea, but doing iteratively is cumbersome.  I found something like this, not sure yet if it works: ccpToAngle(myLocalNode -> convertToNodeSpace(ccpForAngle(myWorldAngle))).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do is to get two reference points, one representing the origin and the other representing the rotation vector. Convert these 2 points to node space, measure the vector between them (subtraction) and convert that to an angle. Here are 2 methods that should be a category of CCNode (note: I refer to self), one to world and the other to node.

```
-(float) convertRotationToWorldSpace:(float)rotation
{
    CGPoint rot = ccpForAngle(-CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(rotation));

    CGPoint worldPt = [self convertToWorldSpace:rot];
    CGPoint worldOriginPt = [self convertToWorldSpace:CGPointZero];

    CGPoint worldVec = ccpSub(worldPt, worldOriginPt);

    return -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(ccpToAngle(worldVec));
}

-(float) convertRotationToNodeSpace:(float)rotation
{
    CGPoint rot = ccpForAngle(-CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(rotation));

    CGPoint nodePt = [self convertToNodeSpace:rot];
    CGPoint nodeOriginPt = [self convertToNodeSpace:CGPointZero];

    CGPoint nodeVec = ccpSub(nodePt, nodeOriginPt);

    return -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(ccpToAngle(nodeVec));
}
```